# for a Trunk port, does vlan id and tagging matter at all?

Tags: tagging, trunk, vlan

In normal conditions (multiple tagged traffic is expected on a trunk port, we shouldn't plug an untagged traffic into a trunk port), why does trunk need a vlan id of itself, and what's the point of tagging on trunk port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VLAN ID separates the traffic - you need to tag frames to indicate which VLAN they belong to when transmitting over a cable.

On many devices you can also forward untagged frames through a VLAN trunk. They will be assigned to the untagged VLAN on the receiving port.

Comment: I think my confusion of this matter arises from the fact that Trunk port always come with VLAN ID of 1. Now I realized that VLAN ID 1 is not something we assigned to the trunk port. It is the default native VLAN ID. So in effect, the trunk port doesn't really need a VLAN ID, and it doesn't need tagging either.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the question as answered if you're satisfied. ;-)